# Bad Request error in uber api

Tags: node.js, express, uber-api

I've been trying to get the uber price estimates endpoint working, but I'm stuck on an error that leads me to a blank page saying, "Bad Request." The console also says "callback not a function" but I can't seem to find out what is wrong.

My route:

```
//  Get an upfront fare before requesting a ride
app.get('/v1.2/estimates/price', function(request, response) {
    // extract the query from the request URL
    var query = request.query;

    // if no query params sent, respond with Bad Request
    if (!query || !query.lat || !query.lng) {
      response.sendStatus(400);
    } else { 
          uber.estimates.getPriceForRouteAsync( {
              "product_id": "33de8094-3dc4-4ca9-8f67-243275f57623", 
              "start_latitude": "38.9597897", 
              "start_longitude": "-94.60699369999999",
              "end_latitude": "39.010969", 
              "end_longitude": "-94.61509899999999"
          })
          .then(function(res) {
              log(res);
          })
          .error(function(err) {
              console.error(err);
          });
    }
});
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Please [check out the README for node-uber](https://github.com/shernshiou/node-uber/blob/master/README.md#get-price-estimates-for-specific-route). The method does not take a JSON object but the arguments in the method call:

`uber.estimates.getPriceForRouteAsync(38.9597897, -94.606994, 39.010969, -94.615098)
.then(function(res) { console.log(res); })
.error(function(err) { console.error(err); });`

Also, the product ID is not needed as [the /estimates/price endpoint returns an array of estimates for each product](https://developer.uber.com/docs/riders/references/api/v1.2/estimates-price-get).

Comment: Are the authorization and content-headers required for the estimates endpoint?

Comment: It's in [the Uber Developer docs: Either server_token or access_token are required as auth](https://developer.uber.com/docs/riders/references/api/v1.2/estimates-price-get#authorization). The content headers for JSON are optional.

Comment: I've adapted to your changes and read about it on the docs and node-uber repo, but I'm still getting the same error. Any ideas on why this is a problem? There is no error in the console.

Comment: Hey @agraebe I am having bit of issue using uber-api, please have a look https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50282763/uber-deeplink-and-universal-url-crashes-android-application?noredirect=1#comment87776275_50282763